# Recursive function to ask for user input in Python with error handling

Tags: python, error-handling, user-input

I'm writing a little Python script that needs information passed by the user. As some parts of my script might throw an exception and therefore break the script if the user input is in the wrong format, I'd like to check it on beforehand. This is a useful measure anyway of course. For a better user experience, I do not want the script to be interrupted if the input was in the wrong format. Instead, the question should be reasked.

Therefore I defined a function for each user input which will check the input before moving on to the next step. This checking is done with the `try`, `except` error handling method to make sure that the script is not interrupted.

#### Here is a minimal example of such a function:

```py
def ask_for_int( prompt = "Please enter an integer:\n" ):
    user_input = input( prompt ).strip()

    # Check if the value can be transformed into a float
    try:
        return int( user_input )
    except:
        ask_for_int( prompt = "You need to pass an integer:\n" )

some_number = ask_for_int()
```

This code works fine as long as I enter an integer. If I pass a string to it, it also recognizes the TypeException and reasks for an integer. Unfortunately, though, the `some_number` variable now does not hold the integer I passed but is empty.

#### To make this clear, have a look at the following:

Let's first add a `print( 'You passed the valid integer: %s' % some_number )` at the end of the previous example. If we now pass, let's say, `123` to the prompt, then the print returns `123`. Hooray!

However, if we pass `abc`, the script will refuse our input and ask for a new number, That's the `except` working here. Now let's fulfill this task and in fact pass an integer, e.g. `321`. The print should return `321`of course because that's the integer that was accepted, isn't it? Well, unfortunately, the output is `None`.

#### Here is the raw output:

**Passing an integer**

```
Please enter an integer:
123
You passed the valid integer: 123
```

**First passing a string, then an integer**

```
Please enter an integer:
abc
You need to pass an integer:
321
You passed the valid integer: None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the result of your recursive call, therefore the function returns `None`.

Where you have:

```
ask_for_int( prompt = "You need to pass an integer:\n" )
```

Write:

```
return ask_for_int( prompt = "You need to pass an integer:\n" )
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy! Thanks! I thought that the `return` in the `try` block was enough because the except calls the function again and if the value now is, in fact, an integer, it would apply to the `try` and thus be returned. But it seems that I misunderstood this concept.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `except` block does not return any value.
I recommend you to change it to:

```
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
    except:
        user_input = ask_for_int(prompt="You need to pass an integer:\n")
    return user_input
```